# Angular with asp.net and multi page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to create angular application were a user see login page and after success of login (3rd party system), the login page send validation request to the server, if the validation is ok, the server sends new html with new ng module. I have tried for testing

```
$scope.doLogin = function () {
        $http.post("Home", "");
    };
```

and in the server

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string session)
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("Application");
    }
```

the Application route has different index.cshtml. the html transfers OK, but the new page does not render. What am I missing/.

Comment: what you are doing does not make sense? It seems you  are calling an MVC Controller instead of calling a Rest Service, Why?

Comment: in terms of security , I dont want to use ui-routing for that. so I am looking for a solution to replace html after login

Comment: Then do not use angular either.

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick

```
$scope.doLogin = function () {

        $window.location.assign("/Home/Index2");

    };
```